# Multiple Samba workgroups

Tags: samba, file-sharing

Samba share "scanning" when just clicking on the network tab works perfect when the workgroup setting matches the windows workgroup

```
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
```

This is fine for a desktop but when I use my laptop and connect to many networks and try to connect to the network shares nothing shows until i update that line with the current workgroup. I can connect if i know the hostname (eg smb://hostname)

Windows PC's list all networks OK, Is there a way i can set Samba to do the same ?

I dont have administrator access to any of the shares and its unlikely the same name will be chosen for the 3.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

you can do that by running multiple Samba instances with different `/etc/smb/smb.conf` files. For example you can have the files `/etc/smb/smb.conf.homenet` and `/etc/smb/smb.conf.worknet` with different `workgroup =` options. You can then start them as root by:

```
service smb.homenet start
service smb.worknet start
```

I've certainly missed something so for more information have a look at:

https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Multiple_Server_Instances